# Unable to do anything with the mesh imported from blender

Tags: solidworks, meshing

I made an object in Blender (default cube), then exported it to `STL`, then imported this `STL` into Solidworks.

Now I see this object just exists and I can do nothing with it.

I can't reference any face of the cube and can't scetch on it. Also I can't use `Mesh Prep Wizard` since it is dimmed.

[image]

What can be done here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it from a graphic body to a mesh body (use the command search at the top right of the screen), and then you can use the Boolean tools to affect it using other mesh bodies.

You will not be able to "sketch on the face", since by their very definition, mesh bodies are made up of vertices, not faces. Native solidworks objects (BREP) *are* made of faces however. If you need to sketch on a face, You can use the three vertices of any triangle to define a plane, and sketch on that.

See below for a demonstration from the same question I previously answered elsewhere on the internet.

[image]